# Get class of returned object by PowerShell command - determine a cmdlet's output data type

Tags: powershell, types, output, scom

In PowerShell, if a command returns an array of one or more objects, I can find out the class of the object by the following method:

```
$ab = SampleCommand
$ab[0].getType()
```

But, how can I find out the default return type of a command if the command returned nothing (array of 0 values)?

Note: For example, I am working on SCOM PowerShell commands, and I am trying to find the default return class type of command `get-scomscadvisoragent`, but it returns nothing as the advisor agent is not configured in my lab setup. Hence, I am not able to get the class of returned object.

Comment: The help information doesn't specify what it returns?

Comment: If something returns nothing, the return type is `$null`/`[System.Void]`.

Comment: Generically speaking, gettype().Name and gettype().DeclaredFields are also two very useful properties of that method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to determine the type of objects a given command outputs in principle, use `(Get-Command <cmd>).OutputType`; in your case:

```
(Get-Command get-scomscadvisoragent).OutputType
```

Note, however, that this only works if the target command has explicitly declared its output types via one or more [`OutputType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_outputtypeattribute) attributes.

---

Cmdlets / advanced functions may alternatively / additionally describe their output types in a less formal way, via the `.OUTPUTS` section of their help text (in comment-based help).
Therefore, if the above didn't work, you can also try:

```
(Get-Help get-scomscadvisoragent).returnvalues
```

The latter information can also be found in the `OUTPUTS` section of the output from
`Get-Help -Full <cmd>`.